# primefaces - PickList -By default all the value should moved to the destination

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces - PickList to displaying source and destination div's like below.
[image]

left side is source and right is destination. If user clicks on move all to right arrow mark its moved to destination. but on the page load i want all the values from source to be moved to the destination.

Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead to set the values to your source you need to set it to your target List.

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //Cities
        List<String> citiesSource = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> citiesTarget = new ArrayList<String>();

        citiesTarget.add("San Francisco");
        citiesTarget.add("London");
        citiesTarget.add("Paris");
        citiesTarget.add("Istanbul");
        citiesTarget.add("Berlin");
        citiesTarget.add("Barcelona");
        citiesTarget.add("Rome");

        cities = new DualListModel<String>(citiesSource, citiesTarget);

        //Themes
        List<Theme> themesSource = service.getThemes().subList(0, 5);
        List<Theme> themesTarget = new ArrayList<Theme>();

        themes = new DualListModel<Theme>(themesSource, themesTarget);

    }
```